# Communicating with Android C2DM using .NET

Tags: android, asp.net, .net, vb.net, android-c2dm

I've set up this function in my web app to send push notifications to Android devices:

```
Private Function SendNotification(ByVal authstring As String) As String
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send")
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.Headers.Add(String.Format("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth={0}", authstring))
    Dim postData As String = String.Format("registration_id={0}&data.payload={1}&collapse_key=0", deviceList.SelectedValue, txtPayload.Text)
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()

    Return responseFromServer
End Function
```

However, whenever I call this function, I get the following error message: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong here? I also tried running this on IIS but that didn't help.

Comment: The authentication request to Google, on the other hand, seems to work fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out after a lot of browsing around. I was missing this line in my code (should be at the first line of the function):

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(sender As _
Object, certificate As X509Certificate, chain As X509Chain, sslPolicyErrors As _
SslPolicyErrors) True
```